# XSLT Navigation of Base64-Encoded XML

Tags: xslt, base64

I am using XSLT to transform a SOAP response. The XML response has one node encoded in Base64. If we decode this node, it becomes XML text, and I need to perform additional operations on the XML decoded from the Base64.

I would like to do the entire transformation and decoding within the XSLT transform.

The XML response looks something like this:

```
        <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
           <env:Header/>
           <env:Body>
              <ns2:runReportResponse 
        xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oxp/service/PublicReportService">
             <ns2:runReportReturn>
        <ns2:reportBytes>PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4KPCEtLUdl 
       bmVyYXRlZCBieSBP
       cmFjbGUgQkkgUHVibGlzaGVyIC1EYXRhZW5naW5lLCBkYXRhbW9kZWw6X0N1c3RvbV9TdXBwbHlf
       Q2hhaW5fTWFuYWdlbWVudF9JbnZlbnRvcnlfTWFuYWdlbWVudF9JdGVtX1ZlbnR1cmVmb3J0aF94
```

I can succssfully call

```
        select="sunBase64:base64Decode($base64Value)"
```

to decode the Base64 node in a

```
    <xsl:variable or <xsl:value-of
```

tag, but I ultimately want to perform additional operations on the XML decoded from Base64, such as the following:

```
    <xsl:for-each select
```

on the variable that was defined by calling base64Decode of com.sun.jersey.core.util.Base64.

The Base64 node can be decoded successfully, and the output looks like this:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!--Generated by Oracle BI Publisher -Dataengine, 
        datamodel:_Custom_Supply_Chain_Management_Inventory_Management_Item_xdm -->
        <DATA_DS><P_ORGANIZATION_ID>300000002559348</P_ORGANIZATION_ID>
        <G_1>
        <ORGANIZATION_NAME>Inventory Organization</ORGANIZATION_NAME> 
       <ORGANIZATIONID>300000002559348</ORGANIZATIONID> 
       <ITEMDESCRIPTION>LUBRICANT|MACHINE LUBE|ML-514|AUTOMOTIVE GEAR OIL||EXTREME 
         PRESSURE|55 GAL/400 LB DRUM|85W-140 VISC|||||||||</ITEMDESCRIPTION> 
       <ITEMNUMBER>527293318</ITEMNUMBER><PRIMARYUOMVALUE>DR</PRIMARYUOMVALUE> 
       <ITEM_ID>300000009810631</ITEM_ID>
        </G_1>
```

As I mentioned earlier, I want to use

```
        <xsl:for-each select="$xmlReportBytes/DATA_DS" >
```

But when I try to run this operation, I get an error in the Java program 
that is running the XSLT transformation. Without the /DATA_DS,this 
operation runs fine, but I need to navigate into the XML that was 
originally encoded in Base64.

How can I resolve this error, or is there an alternative solution? I would like to do all of the operations within XSLT.

Comment: First, everybody is going to tell you that you should not be using internal class `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder`. Second, in order to iterate, the result of `sunBase64:base64Decode()` must be an iterable XSLT/XPath data type (node-set, sequence or map). I asume you are getting a string. If that is the case, you will need to reparse.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an XSLT 3.0 processor with support for the EXPath Binary module then you can decode the base64 text using the `bin:decode-string()` function (see http://expath.org/spec/binary#decode-string) and then you can parse the resulting XML using the fn:parse-xml() function.

Without these functions, you'll need to call vendor-specific extension functions, and it then depends entirely on what XSLT processor you are using.

You can get these functions if you use Saxon-PE or Saxon-EE.

Note that decoding base64 produces a stream of octets, and to decode these octets as text you need to know the encoding of the text, e.g. iso-8859-1 or utf-8.